# Struts2Jquery Grid

Tags: jquery, struts2, grid

I am using **Struts2Jquery Grid plugin**. I have some questions which stops my work.

1. I am creating ID column
   but while editing I am not getting the id value in my action class and if 
   I am setting editable is true then I wll get the value of ID column in my action class.So how can I get non editable filed value in action class.
2. In the Edit and Save form I have select box, on change value of selectbox I want to disable or enable some field.
3. In my both form say I have three textbox and I am entering some values in first two textboxes when I go to third textbox I want the difference of first two textboxes values on the focus of thired textbox.
4. Is it possible to use jquery UI multiselect in struts2jquery Gird like erichynds and how I can implement this?

So can somebody help me how can I achieve this?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the wiki of jqgrid [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs), i think that will help you to understand how `jqgrid` works. You can also see a detailed examples on struts2 jquery [here](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action).